# Cache accumulation of long running spark application

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

We have long-running spark streaming application in our hadoop cluster. The problem is cache directory size is growing continuously until stop spark application.

Directory : yarn/local/usercache

Now, we restart application periodically. Not smart way...
Can limit the size of directory?

File list example

```
-r-x------ 1 yarn hadoop 169M Sep 20 14:53 /data/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/username/filecache/81/appname-SNAPSHOT.jar
-r-x------ 1 yarn hadoop 169M Sep 20 15:55 /data/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/username/filecache/84/appname-SNAPSHOT.jar
-r-x------ 1 yarn hadoop 169M Sep 20 16:02 /data/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/username/filecache/87/appname-SNAPSHOT.jar
-r-x------ 1 yarn hadoop 169M Sep 20 17:30 /data/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/username/filecache/90/appname-SNAPSHOT.jar
-r-x------ 1 yarn hadoop 169M Sep 21 10:55 /data/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/username/filecache/93/appname-SNAPSHOT.jar
-r-x------ 1 yarn hadoop 169M Sep 21 11:01 /data/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/username/filecache/96/appname-SNAPSHOT.jar
-r-x------ 1 yarn hadoop 169M Sep 21 12:14 /data/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/username/filecache/99/appname-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: you need you add more info, example, spark version, are you using structured streaming, are you do stateful aggregations, what is the eviction criteria for state/ cache etc

Comment: Basically we using hdp 2.6.4. It consists of hdfs 2.7.3, yarn+mr also 2.7.3, Spark2 2.2.0. We using structured streaming that consumes kafka 0.11.0.2.

Comment: Yes logic has stateful aggregation. More specifically the one of the large file is yarn/local/usercache/our_user/filecache/150/our_application.jar